# How to compare date field with None in django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a model where there is a Date field.

I'm trying to query the model by passing date object or a null value.

The query should behave in different ways based on the input provided in ORM query.

I'll be passing two variables to ORM query `st_date` and `exp_date`. `exp_date` can be None sometimes.

I need to query the model and fetch all the records which has the `scheduled_end_date` greater than provided exp_date if there is some value in exp_date. If not, it should not consider the filter at all.

**models.py:**

```
class DtModel(models.Model):
    scheduled_start_date = DateField()
    scheduled_end_date = DateField()
```

**ORM query:**

```
st_date="2020-05-01"
exp_date=None
DtModel.objects.filter(scheduled_start_date__gte=st_date, scheduled_end_date__lte=exp_date)
```

It's throwing an error when the `exp_date` is null when it tries to compare `None` and `date field`?

> ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value

Answer (score 1):

Why would you query a null value...
If None means you wanna filter `x > date` instead `x > date and < date` just use a large date value.

```
if not exp_date:
  st_date="2099-01-01"
```

Comment: There is a requirement to filter based on that `exp_date` if it has some value.
If not, completely ignore the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `None` as query value in Django. To filter rows with null values, you have to use `scheduled_end_date__isnull=True`. Based on your comment on @SakuraFreak's answer, the below should work

```
st_date="2020-05-01"
exp_date=None
if exp_date:  # Apply filter only if exp_date is not null
    DtModel.objects.filter(scheduled_start_date__gte=st_date, scheduled_end_date__lte=exp_date)
```